# Can't build release APK flutter when debug is fine

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

here's the error

> - Where: Build file 'D:\Work From Office\Form\form\android\app\build.gradle' line: 30
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
> > Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 37s Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done    40.3s
> Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

where my build.gradle line 30 is this

```
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
```

i was following all the flutter.dev give but, when i build the apk it comes like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Key Store file use `\\` instead of `\`. Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: you mean at key.properties
storeFile= ?